# why e.preventDefault not working for event "touchmove" added to div where is there a google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, preventdefault

Why e.preventDefault not works in this case?

i added event `touchmove` for a div where inside there's a google maps:

```
 document.getElementById("googleMap").addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var touch = e.touches[0];
 if(e.touches.length == 2){
  //This means there are two finger move gesture on screen
  map.setOptions({draggable:true});
 }
 else{
  map.setOptions({draggable:false});
 }
}, false);
```

This is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lu4exkp7/4/

if i touch (and move) the screen (of map) with two fingers so the map will be draggable, but if touch with only finger the map is not draggable...

`e.preventDefault` should not block the event mechanism ? so the code inside why works ?

i don't understand if `e.preventDefault` has sense in this code...